# Applying a small amount of code to every page on a domain

Tags: php, html, css

I have set up a sub domain on my companies website.  I would like to have a small amount of code (like an absolute positioned DIV) to be displayed on ALL pages, without each page actually containing the code itself.  I seem to remember that geocities used to do such things  in the past.

Because I would like to put like a little image and a title or something in the background of the sub domain, that would feature on every page.  It would look quite professional really.

Anyone got an idea whether this is possible, or whether I'm dreaming a dream that can't be dreamt.

Comment: are you using virtual sub domains ? (e.g a blog system ? )
what is your control panel ? cpanel,da,plesk or ...?
you are trying to do it on a shared hosting or on a dedicated server? 
give us more infromation , post your code.

Comment: @RezaSh - see machours answer.  If you had needed that information I would have given it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) or [auto_append_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) php.ini directives

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i understands your requirement correctly ...

You can Write the mark up for this  div in a file...  include this file in every php file which outputs Markup for browser to show  some page ...

Thanks